# Unexpectedly found 'nil' when running app on Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm practicing creating a few different apps at the moment, and I'm trying to execute a simple pass data task from one storyboard to another.

- I want to segue from a '+' button on the main view controller, to 'create a goal' on the 'Create Goal' view controller. (That works fine)
- I then want the user to fill in three textfields on the CreateGoalViewController, and submit the data via a Create Goal button.
- The user will then be segued back to the homepage main view controller, and the data from the three textfields entered into the three labels on the main view controller.

However, I'm getting the following error whenever I try to run the app:

*Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/jon/Desktop/Practice App Development/PracticePassDataOpna/PracticePassDataOpna/ViewController.swift, line 28
2020-04-18 16:15:05.181014+0100 PracticePassDataOpna[8267:419753] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/jon/Desktop/Practice App Development/PracticePassDataOpna/PracticePassDataOpna/ViewController.swift, line 28*

For reference, here are my View Controllers:

Main View Controller:

[image: Main View Controller]

Create View Controller:

[image: Create View Controller]

And here is my code:

Main VC:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var goalName: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var targetDate: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var longDescription: UILabel!

    var goalText = ""
    var dateText = ""
    var descriptionText = ""


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        goalName.text = goalText
        targetDate.text = dateText
        longDescription.text = descriptionText
    }

    @IBAction func createButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "createSegue", sender: self)
    }


}
```

Create VC:

```
import UIKit

class CreateGoalViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var goalInput: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var dateInput: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionInput: UITextField!

    var goalAdd = ""
    var dateAdd = ""
    var descriptionAdd = ""



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func createGoalButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        self.goalAdd = goalInput.text!
        self.dateAdd = dateInput.text!
        self.descriptionAdd = descriptionInput.text!

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "createGoalSegue", sender: self)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var vc = segue.destination as! ViewController
        vc.goalText = self.goalAdd
        vc.dateText = self.dateAdd
        vc.descriptionText = self.descriptionAdd
    }

}
```

And just to make things clearer - this is line 28:

```
goalName.text = goalText
```

Any help would be great - I don't understand why it's not working considering it's am empty string? Maybe that's the problem. Cheers!

Comment: The most probable immediate problem is `goalName` being nil ithough the declaration says you'll never let that happen.  You can set a breakpoint on that line to verify whether that's true.  (Maybe you have a missing connection in a storyboard?)

Comment: ViewController is your initial ViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this function:

```
@IBAction func createGoalButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        self.goalAdd = goalInput.text!
        self.dateAdd = dateInput.text!
        self.descriptionAdd = descriptionInput.text!

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "createGoalSegue", sender: self)

    }
```

In this function you have force unwrapped an optional where there is no value. Force-unwrapping is very prone to errors so you should instead write the function as:

```
@IBAction func createGoalButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

            let x = "You never added a goal"
            let y = "You never added a date"
            let z = "You never added a description"

            self.goalAdd = goalInput.text ?? print(x)
            self.dateAdd = dateInput.text ?? print(y)
            self.descriptionAdd = descriptionInput.text ?? print(z)

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "createGoalSegue", sender: self)

        }
```

Comment: Yep, whenever I use optionals I always like to use the ?? instead of ! because ! always gives "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: *because ! **always** gives "Fatal error*, No, it doesn't, for example the `text` property of an `UITextField` is never `nil` although it's optional.